# Swagger no funciona una vez publicado el Site

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

estoy intentando hacer una API Rest en ASP .Net CORE 5.
En modo depuración de Visual Studio, Swagger funciona perfectamente, pero una vez publicad el Site en IIS, a pesar de que la Api funciona perfectamente, el EndPoint de Swagger no responde(404)
Alguien me puede echar una mano porfavor ?

Comment: En algunos sitios la configuración de swagger está desactivada para producción. Revisa si tienes algo así (en symfony por ej, puedes decir que los entornos de dev y test puedan acceder a swagger pero no en prod)

Comment: Estás en lo cierto, respondo mi pregunta con la solución, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo, gracias @Jakala.
En Startup.cs, por defecto viene activado solo en entorno de desarrollo:

```
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Site v1"));
        }
```

basta con sustituirlo con `env.IsProduction()` o eliminar condicional si queremos que funcione en ambos.

Comment: Muchas gracias eso me paso a mi y no lo había notado. creo que es el desvelo